# Export emails from DirectAdmin

Tags: admin

is there's a way to export all my emails accounts name from my DirectAdmin

i have like 1000 email users i cant type it one by one

i hope i find a way to export all this emails name into text or something similar

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, from the shell you can get all accounts on the DirectAdmin database but without the @domain.com Like

zeroic

stack

over

flow

so i export all to text file and added a sign like (( ~ )) after the last letter then used the note pad Ctrl + H to replace (( ~ )) With (( @domain.com ))

thanks for help